# Generate N points following a a normal distribution

Tags: random, fortran, normal-distribution, probability-density

Does anyone know how could Ieasily generate N random numbers following a normal distribution, with a mean mu and a standard deviation sigma, in Fortran 90?
Or even the logic process to produce the N values?

Comment: what about RANLIB? https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f_src/ranlib/ranlib.html

Comment: Have you tried googling? There are many codes lying around like this one http://www.cmiss.org/openCMISS/wiki/RandomNumberGenerationWithOpenMP Slightly improved version https://bitbucket.org/LadaF/elmm/src/dcee6b8ac6023bb579563424856d937062cdcdee/src/rng_par_zig.f90?at=master

Answer (score 2):

(Not a fortran-programmer)

The **standard / your compiler defines some random-function for uniform random-values** within `(0,1)`. (example: [Gnu Fortran Docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/RAND.html#RAND))

Now just select one of the well-known and specialized sampling-algorithms designed for gaussian-sampling listed [at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Generating_values_from_normal_distribution).

The most well-known:

- [Box-Muller transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform)
- [Polar-method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marsaglia_polar_method)
- [Ziggurat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziggurat_algorithm)

Answer (score -3):

```
PROGRAM XX
IMPLICIT NONE
REAL                 :: Std_Dev   = .1
REAL                 :: Variance 
INTEGER              :: N         = 100
REAL, DIMENSION(100) :: RData
REAL< PARAMETER      :: Steigler  = /(1.0/6.28)/

Variance = Std_Dev**2      !variance from the std deviation maybe with some steigler or 2.88 distribution
CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(RData)  !distributed as 0-1

RData = RData * Variance   !RData is now with variance
RData = RData + Mean       !RData is now with variance and mean

WRITE(*,*)'Data=',RData

!... Insert your statistics code here to debug it...

END PROGRAM
```

Comment: *"following a normal distribution"*